# Integration problems

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Given that

$$\int^4_0 f(x)\,dx = 8 $$

Find the value of $m$ if

$$\int^4_0 ( f(x) + mx)\,dx = 12 $$

What I did was -

$$\int^4_0 ( 8 + mx)\,dx = 12$$

I believe this is wrong ...

Can I get a hint on how do I combine them both ?

Comment: Hint: Try splitting up the integral, then substituting.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $$\int_0^4 (f(x) +mx)\, \mathrm{d}x = \int_0^4 f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x + \int_0^4 mx \,\mathrm{d}x$$

Answer (score 2):

It is obviously not true. Just split the sum in the integral by using linearity and then substitute the value.

$$\int_{0}^{4} (f(x)+mx)dx= \int_{0}^{4} f(x)dx +\int_{0}^{4} mx dx=12$$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}\int_0^4\bigl(f(x)+mx\bigr)\,dx&=\int_0^4f(x)\,dx+\int_0^4mx\,dx\\&=8+8m\end{align*}So...

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^4(f(x)+mx)dx=\int_0^4(f(x))dx+\int_0^4(mx)dx=8+m\int_0^4xdx=8+m\left[\frac{x^2}{2}\right]_0^4=8+8m=12\implies m=\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\int_0^4 (f(x)+mx)dx=\int_0^4 f(x)dx +\int_0^4 mx dx = 8 +\int_0^4 mx\; dx \stackrel{\mbox{set}}=12$

Can you solve the resulting equation for $m$?

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_0^4 (f (x)+mx)dx=$$
$$\int_0^4f (x )dx+\int_0^4mxdx $$
by linearity

$$=8+m\Bigl [\frac {x^2}{2}\Bigr]_0^4$$

$$=8+8m=12$$
thus $$m=\frac {1}{2} $$